# jq cannot iterate over number with join

Tags: json, jq

I would like to add some values from json file separated by pipe. It's working well so far until a value is a number and not a string.

Here what I've done so far: `jq -r '.content[] | {seasonTitle, number, name} | join("|")' file.json`

I've tried to convert number to string without any success `jq -r '.content[] | {seasonTitle, "episodeNumber|tostring", name} | join("|")' file.json`

**Actual Result:**

```
Top Master||Last Chance / Season 12
Top Master||Épisode 8 / Season 12
Top Master||Épisode 7 / Season 12
```

**Expected Result:**

```
Top Master|236|Last Chance / Season 12
Top Master|235|Épisode 8 / Season 12
Top Master|234|Épisode 7 / Season 12
```

**Here the file.json**

```
{
  "page": 0,
  "size": 3,
  "count": 3,
  "content": [
    {
      "name": "Last Chance / Season 12",
      "releaseDate": "2008",
      "duration": 2100,
      "episodeNumber": 236,
      "title": "Last Chance / Season 12",
      "seasonTitle": "Top Master"
    },
    {
      "name": "Épisode 8 / Season 12",
      "releaseDate": "2008",
      "duration": 7320,
      "episodeNumber": 235,
      "title": "Épisode 8 / Season 12",
      "seasonTitle": "Top Master"
    },
    {
      "name": "Épisode 7 / Season 12",
      "releaseDate": "2008",
      "duration": 7200,
      "episodeNumber": 234,
      "title": "Épisode 7 / Season 12",
      "seasonTitle": "Top Master"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You already have the right filter, you are just using the wrong field name. It's called `episodeNumber`, not `number`. Also, conversion to string is not necessary as `join` takes care of it. Here's your full filter: `.content[] | {seasonTitle, episodeNumber, name} | join("|")` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/rB2UoD2MRr)

Comment: You right, my mistake, but I have the error `jq: error (at file.json:31): string ("|") and number (236) cannot be added`

Comment: What version are you working on? I cannot reproduce it with jq v1.6 (neither locally, nor on jqplay.org).

Comment: jq --version `jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe`

Comment: nice it's working well @pmf thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `join` to concatenate values of different types, which works fine under jq v1.6:

```
.content[] | {seasonTitle, episodeNumber, name} | join("|")
```

```
Top Master|236|Last Chance / Season 12
Top Master|235|Épisode 8 / Season 12
Top Master|234|Épisode 7 / Season 12
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/rB2UoD2MRr)

However, with jq v1.5 it doesn't, and you need to convert non-strings to strings using `tostring`. As you are using a shortcut to create an object for `join`, introducing this conversion sacrifices the conciseness of your solution. So either stick with it:

```
.content[] | {seasonTitle, episodeNumber: (.episodeNumber | tostring), name} | join("|")
```

Or use an array instead, as you are going for the values only anyway:

```
.content[] | [.seasonTitle, (.episodeNumber | tostring), .name] | join("|")
```